# Direct experimental observation of magnetic orbital quantum number $m_l$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, spectroscopy

Is there an experimental way to observe magnetic quantum number $m_l$ values directly, the way electron spin was detected by Stern Gerlach experiment or proton's spin by nuclear magnetic resonance experiments? The Zeeman effect comes to mind, but in the Zeeman effect one cannot ignore the electron spin. In short, how can one experimentally or spectroscopically see that if $l=2$,, $m_l$ will be -2, -1, 0, +1, and +2?

Comment: A hint to the literature of fine-structure spectroscopists: an $\ell=2$ state is sometimes known as a “quintet” because of its splitting into five sublevels. See also singlet, doublet, triplet, etc.

Comment: Let us take the example of the famous Na doublet. How does this directly indicate or hint at the $m_l$ value? This doublet is visible without an external magnetic field. Wikipedia on the hand indicates the $m_l$ should appear in the presence of magnetic field hence the name *magnetic*.

Comment: @M.Farooq So just to confirm - you want an experiment that *only* splits the orbital magnetic components, but does not lift the electron's spin degeneracy? So you want something that only couples to the orbital angular momentum ... ?

Comment: @SuperCiocia, Yes, you are right.

Comment: I am going to guess that you cannot, since the electrons will *always* have spin. So your only hope is to find an atom where the Lande' factors for $L$ is much larger than that for $S$ so that the spin splitting is "hidden"...

Comment: For an experimental history, I enjoyed Tomonaga’s “The Story of Spin.”

Comment: @rob, Thanks, this book looks good. I will try to get hold of it.

Answer (score 2):

A hint to the literature of fine-structure spectroscopists: an $ℓ=2$ state is sometimes known as a “quintet” because of its splitting into five sublevels. See also singlet, doublet, triplet, etc.

You suggest in a comment that we consider the famous sodium doublet, which is visible without any magnetic field. That doublet is a spin-orbit effect: the $3p$ first excited state in sodium can have $j=1/2$ or $j=3/2$, depending on the orientation of the electron spin relative to its orbit.

[image: Zeeman effect in sodium]
([source](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/sodzee.html))

In a magnetic field, the energy degeneracy among the various $m_j$ is broken, and the two lines in the sodium doublet split in ways that reveal their multiplicity.  This diagram suggests that the $\frac12 \to \frac12$ transition subdivides into two doublets.
The $\frac32\to\frac12$ transition divides into six pieces, rather than eight, because the transition from $m_j=-3/2$ to $m_j=+1/2$ would require the photon to carry away at least two units of angular momentum.
(It’s not immediately obvious to me why the six transitions in the $\frac32\to\frac12$ transition should be equally spaced, as sketched, but I’m prepared to believe they are.)

Magnetic splitting was actually discovered by Zeeman in this sodium transition, but this transition is an example of the “anomalous Zeeman effect.” [One description](https://math.ucr.edu/home//baez/spin/node10.html).

Comment: In response to clarifying comments on the question: the last link in the answer states that the “normal Zeeman effect” has an $m_\ell$ selection rule, contrasted with the $m_j$ selection rule for the anomalous effect. I don’t have a catalogue of Zeeman transitions handy to hunt for a better example, though.

Comment: This question was asked by a student in SE Chemistry in an obscure way but it had intrigued me as well. Zeeman effect is indirectly allowing us to see $m_l$ because of the coupling with $m_s$, we have to talk about $m_j$. What about the Stark effect? Does it also allow us to see $m_l$ values?

Comment: The Stark effect seems to cause $s$-$p$ orbital hybridization, which means that $\ell$ is no longer a good quantum number. It seems, on some more reading and some dim recollections, that the Zeeman effect describes the weak-field regime where $m_j$ is a good quantum  number but $m_\ell$ and $m_s$ are not. In the strong-field limit, $j$ goes away and you recover separate quantum numbers for $\ell$ and $s$, as first described by Paschen and Back. In an atom with even $Z$, Zeeman/Paschen-Back splitting of $s=0\to0$ transitions directly probes $m_\ell$. Candidate atoms include helium and cadmium.